# using comboboxes and textbox for date of birth

Tags: c#

I combined 2 text boxes and text box. Don't know how to convert the string to datetime.

```
string DOb  = $"{comboMM.SelectedValue}, {ComboDD.SelectedValue}, {txtYear.Text"";
string Query = "Insert into dbo.membertable(Given_Names, Last_Name, passport_No, Ctry_Origin, gender, M_status, DOb,MarAnn, Phone_No,Email,branch,Unit,H_address,city,states,Country,famdfrd_Name,famfrd_Number,famfrd_rship) Values('" + txtnames.Text + "','" + txtFamilyname.Text + "','" + txtPassport.Text + "','" + txtCountry.Text + "','" + ComboGender.SelectedItem + "','" + ComboMStatus.SelectedItem + "','" + DateB.Value.ToShortDateString() + "','" +  MarAnn + "','" + txtPhoneNo.Text + "','" + txtEmailAdd.Text + "','" + ComboBranch.SelectedItem + "','" + ComboUnit.SelectedItem + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtCity.Text + "','" + ComboState.SelectedItem + "','" + ComboCountry.SelectedItem + "','" + txtrelative.Text + "','" + TxtRphone.Text + "','" + txtRelationship.Text + "');";

ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PottersDB"];
String connectionString = conSettings.ConnectionString;
try
{

    con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
    dr  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    MessageBox.Show("Member Successfully Added");
    Reset_Page();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Do you mean convert to `DateTime` in `SQL` or in `C#`?

Comment: As @LarsTech said, parameterize your query first. You can either construct a new `DateTime` object with your date components and assign that to the appropriate parameter, or you can just get rid of the three separate controls and use a control that's designed to accept a date directly. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: In C#, I am not sure how to work it out.

Comment: @ Joe Farrell I want to use the combox boxes and text box because its easier for what I am designing the application for.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. You may want to consider using `ExecuteNonQuery` for an INSERT statement - readers (which are also disposable) are used with SELECT statements. Use `DateTime.Parse` to convert a string to a DateTime (there are lots of overloads for how to do this). You seem to be using commas to separate the parts of the date - which [CultureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is your machine using?

Comment: *"I want to use the combox boxes and text box because its easier for what I am designing the application for"* - usually when I hear this, it's from people who haven't considered the user experience, or how the control can be used, but let's assume that isn't the case here, and let's remember that this shifts the validation of the date (e.g. Feb,31,2018) to being your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, using Parameters in your query will simplify your code.

Please see the below code for an example. I have added a few extra comments to suggest improvements to your supplied code.

```
// Create a DateTime object from your controls, instead of a string representation.
var year = int.Parse(txtYear.Text);
var month = int.Parse(comboMM.SelectedValue);
var day = int.Parse(ComboDD.SelectedValue);
var dateOfBirth = new DateTime(year, month, day);

// Use parameters in your query instead of appending the string values
var query = "Insert into dbo.membertable(Given_Names, Last_Name, DOb, OtherFields) Values(@GivenNames, @LastName, @DOB, @OtherParameters);";

// Wrap your SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using blocks to ensure they are disposed correctly.
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PottersDB"].ConnectionString;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNames", txtnames.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtFamilyname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateOfBirth);

        // As the query is just inserting, there's no need to create a data reader.
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned by Avrohom Yisroel, a [DatePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) control seems more suited to your application. It allows the user to select a date, which you can access from the SelectedDate property of the object. This would save you creating a TextBox for the year and two ComboBoxes for the day/month.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use a date picker instead. That's what they are there for, it's what the user expects, it validates the input for you, it gives you a DateTime instead of a string you have to covert...

There's more, but that should be plenty!